# Bayesian MCMC when a likelihood function cannot be written

Tags: bayesian, estimation, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood

Consider Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) to sample from the posterior distribution of some unknown parameter $\theta$:

$$P(\theta|X) \propto P(X|\theta)P(\theta)$$

Where $X$ is the observed data, $P(X|\theta)$ is the likelihood function and $P(\theta)$ is the prior distribution.

My question concerns the case where an expression for $P(X|\theta)$ can not be written however for a given value of $\theta$ it is possible to numerically draw samples from $P(X|\theta)$.

**How can we draw samples from $P(\theta|X)$?** Links to literature would be appreciated.

My idiotic and computationally inefficient approach would be: for the current value of $\theta$ in the markov chain draw an arbitrarily large number of samples from $P(X|\theta)$ and fit an empirical likelihood function. However my intuition is that since the number of draws from $P(X|\theta)$ is arbitrary only one draw needs to be taken but it is not clear to me how this would work.

Comment: Search terms that might be useful for you would be 'intractable likelihood' and 'doubly intractable posterior' and possibly 'approximate bayesian computation'

Comment: @conjectures or even just "how does MCMC work".

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat: actually, sampling with an intractable likelihood function is a pretty advanced topic. Pretty sure googling "how does MCMC work" will not give the OP much insight on how to do that. I think you are referring to intractable posterior distributions.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page: Approximate Bayesian computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) seems to be an excellent starting point.

Comment: see also Hartig et al., Statistical inference for stochastic simulation models - theory and application Ecol. Lett., 2011, 14, 816-827, http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1461-0248.2011.01640.x/abstract

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The situation you describe where $p(x|\theta)$ cannot be computed but simulations from $p(\cdot|\theta)$ can be produced is call a *generative model*. It leads to likelihood-free resolutions like

1. ABC ([Approximate Bayesian computation](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-011-9288-2)), which is indeed properly introduced in the [Wikipedia page: Approximate Bayesian computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation);
2. synthetic likelihood, as in [Wood (2010)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v466/n7310/full/nature09319.html), where the unknown model $p(\cdot|\theta)$ is approximated by a Normal $\text{N}(\mu(\theta),\sigma(\theta)^2)$, where $\mu(\theta),\sigma(\theta)$ are estimated by simulation;
3. Bayesian solutions derived from indirect inference, as in [Drovandi et al. (2015)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1425492441)