# How to incorporate $p(x)$ in Bayes rule with Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo

I want to estimate $p(Q|x)$. I have an observed distribution for $p(x)$ - i.e. samples, and I can compute $p(x|Q)$ using MC simulation (not analytically). I have no belief about $p(Q)$ so we can make it uniform. We can use Bayes rule to define
$$ p(Q|x) = \frac{p(x|Q)~p(Q)}{p(x)} $$
So, I can sample from $p(Q)$ and run these through the simulation to get $p(x|Q)$, but I'm not sure how to incorporate $p(x)$ in the context of these samples / simulations. Should I literally to divide the probabilities for matched values of $x$?

Comment: Are you sure it's $p(x)$, not $p(x|Q)$, that you have a parametric form of? Usually it's the _integrated_ likelihood that is intractable, not the likelihood itself. Anyway, if it's really the likelihood you don't have in closed form, you may want to look at ['likelihood-free' Bayesian inference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/268675).

Comment: Thanks - I am sure it is $p(x)$. Here $x$ is observed data, which can be used to estimate $Q$ with nonzero bias and variance. I'm proposing a way to adjust the bias, but I want to quantify / illustrate how variance in $x$ is maintained as variance in the estimated $Q | x$.

Answer (score 3):

In case you did not follow the link provided by [Durden](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/71679/durden), here is the basic approach to [likelihood-free / approximate Bayesian computation (ABC)](https://statistique.cuso.ch/fileadmin/statistique/lectures-christian.pdf) of $p(Q|x^\text{obs})$:

1. Simulate $Q$ from the prior $p(Q)$
2. Simulate $x$ from the sampling distribution $p(x|Q)$
3. Accept $Q$ if $d(x,x^\text{obs})<\epsilon$ else reject

where the value of $\epsilon$ is chosen as small as possible while allowing for a sufficient number of acceptance in an acceptable time.

Comment: Thanks - I have edited the question to remove "parametric form for $p(x)$" to avoid this confusion